# Sum of matrices in 3-dimensional object of variable dimensions without looping

Tags: arrays, r, performance, matrix, vectorization

I have a 3-dimensional object in R, which contains n square matrices. For example:

```
myObject[,,1] # returns a square matrix
myObject[,,2] # returns a square matrix of the same size
...
```

All the matrices within the object are of the same size. I'd like to add all matrices together, **without** a loop. This is simple enough if I know how many matrices are in the object. For example:

```
matrixSum <- myObject[,,1] + myObject[,,2] + myObject[,,3]
```

The problem is, I need to do this for several thousand such objects, and there are a variable number of matrices in each object. Is there any way I can do this without a loop? In a sense, I'd like to try to "vectorize" this summation.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with a `for` loop here, the following will work no matter how many matrices you have in `myObject`: `matrixSum <- matrix(0, dim(myObject)[[1]], dim(myObject)[[2]]);
for(i in seq_len(dim(myObject)[[3]])) matrixSum <- matrixSum + myObject[,,i];
matrixSum`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most convient, but certainly not the fastest, is to use `apply`:

```
matrixSum <- apply(myObject, c(1,2), sum)
```

Example

```
myObject <- array(c(1,2,3),dim = c(3,4,3))
myObject
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3

apply(myObject, c(1,2), sum)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    3    3    3
[2,]    6    6    6    6
[3,]    9    9    9    9
```

Addition:

Using `rowSums` should be must faster:

```
rowSums(myObject, dims = 2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    3    3    3
[2,]    6    6    6    6
[3,]    9    9    9    9
```

Comment: Why is it not fastest? Does apply still use a loop in the background? Or do you say that for another reason? I'm definitely looking for computational efficiency.

Comment: @nsw `apply` is a loop, yes.  But it's designed for work with matrices and arrays so it may not be too bad in this situation.